# Is this kind of design pattern?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

Suppose we have oversimplified code like this:

```
class A{
public:
    template<typename T1, typename T2>
    void work(T1 a, T2 b){
        do_something1(a, b);
        do_something2(a, b);
        do_something3(a, b);
    }

private:
    template<typename T1, typename T2>
    void do_something1(T1 a, T2 b);

    template<typename T1, typename T2>
    void do_something2(T1 a, T2 b);

    template<typename T1, typename T2>
    void do_something3(T1 a, T2 b);
};
```

All functions `do_somethingXX` have same or similar template parameters and probably have some boilerplate code inside.

However, if you refactor like this:

```
class A{
public:
    template<typename T1, typename T2>
    void work(T1 a, T2 b){
        A_Processor<T1, T2> processor(a, b);

        processor();
    }
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
class A_Processor{
public:
    A_Processor(T1 &a, T2 &b) : a(a), b(b){}

    operator()(){
        do_something1();
        do_something2();
        do_something3();
    }

private:
    void do_something1();
    void do_something2();
    void do_something3();

private:
    T1 &a;
    T2 &b;
};
```

Code is much clear and boilerplate disappear. Also compiler optimize `A_Processor` away, so `A_Processor` is zero cost abstraction.

One can give same example without using templates.

Is this kind of design pattern?

Second question if `A` is class `A` what "thing" `A_Processor` represents?

Comment: `A_Processor` is simply a "functor" in this case. I would say as far as design patterns go, this would likely be a [facade pattern.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern)

Comment: @CoryKramer one big "functor", but probably you are right.

Comment: If a and b are so closely related that they are the parameters to 3 different methods then they should probably be members of an object themselves (Perhaps a generic object).   After that it becomes a series of calls that all take the same one parameter--no boilerplate.  After this refactor you will probably find that much of the code in the do_something methods actually belong in your new object so they may refactor much smaller/you may get rid of one.  I know I'm just guessing but it usually does work out that way.